# save result from .foreach to .map

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway I can store the result from .foreach to be used in .map. 
I have 2 arrays. I would like to count how many times each object in array1 occurs in array2. I could probably delcare another global array and push the counter from each .foreach iteration in that, but I am trying to do this with .map.

```
const array1 = [{"name": "Fred" , "age": 22} , {"name": "Fred" , "age": 22},  {"name": "Greg", "age":23}];
const array2 = [{"name": "Fred" , "age": 22} , {"name": "Greg", "age" : 26}];

let obj = array1[0];

function counter(obj, array){
 let count = 0;
for (let i=0;i< array.length; ++i)
{
  if(JSON.stringify(array[i]) === JSON.stringify(obj))
  {
    ++count; 
  }
}
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}


Array.prototype.containsObject = function (obj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this[i]) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

array1.forEach(element => counter(element, array2));

const map1 = array1.map(array1.forEach(element => counter(element, array2)));
```

Comment: So what do you want the output to be? A simple counter? Or would you like to remove the elements in `array1` that do not occur in `array2`?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't have return statement (doesn't return anything)...probably you should use `filter`

Comment: the output should be an array which indicates how many times an object from the first array occurs in the second array.

Comment: Can you add an example output please @user2371290?

Comment: @user2371290, Whether this is your expected result? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/gOaegPv .. The object with name as Fred alone  has count 1 as it matches with array1 and array2 with name and age as same..

Answer (score 0):

forEach doesn't return anything: so it is needless here. That would shorten your code to:

```
const map1 = array1.map(array1);
```

That is obvious no gain. You should use filter instead:

```
const map1 = array1.filter(element => counter(element,array2)>0);
```

Comment: It isn't `array1.map(array1)`, it's `array1.map(e => undefined)` because that's what `forEach` returns.